# Ubuntu lock loop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Curently every time I try to use the SUDO command I have the classic "this user is not in sudo this incident will be reported" so I try to log in su But FOR SOME Reason SU is locked.

So currently Im on a brand new ubuntu OS, but I cannot type any command, cannot solve the issue of sudo and can't access root because I cannot type any sudo command.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: "So currently Im on a brand new ubuntu OS."  So reinstall from Live Ubuntu USB, overwriting the old installation -- there's nothing to lose, from your comment. Creating the USB and installation is < one hour. A normal installation allows the user to use *sudo* with her or his password. You do know that there is *no prompt* during password entry for sudo (i.e., it's done blind)?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik with regards to *A normal installation allows the user to use sudo with her or his password.* I recently installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu with all the default settings and my main/only was also not added to the sudoers file (though I was able to use `su` to add it.)

Comment: Why can’t you login as root and add your user to the sudo group? What step are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: not sure if Ubuntu is similar to Debian in the following regard. When installing Debian, if you do not provide a password for root, then root is effectively locked out, so if your regular user is not a sudoer (though, why that would happen is a mystery, but then Ubuntu is a mystery anyway), then your screwed (unless you fix this by booting from a so called "live linux" and make the appropriate fixes)

Comment: I have install a brand new ubuntu and when I want to do an apt update sudo told me I'm not on the user list and this incident will be reported but I can't add my user account to the sudo list because I need root priviledge but since root didn't ask me to set a password I'm lock

Comment: @Maselia, is it a physical install of Ubuntu or it's Ubuntu setup in a VM?

Comment: It is a VM with ubuntu on virtualbox.

Comment: , and you set up using the VirtualBox auto-setup process... It seems that that's the reason for not being included in the sudoers in the first place (I did the same which is why I had the same) see https://superuser.com/a/1755286/368970

Comment: Can you chroot from a live system like in Arch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your user wasn't included in the sudoers file (unlike typical Ubuntu installations, as noted by @DrMoishePippik in the comments) is because Ubuntu was set up using VirtualBox's ***Unattended Installation*** feature that added your user for you, and it seems (see the answer here https://superuser.com/a/1755286/368970) that their setup process doesn't add the user to the sudoers.

But they do set the ***root*** password for you to be the same as the main user...

So the solution would be:

1. In the terminal, enter `su -` and press enter
2. When asked for the password (of the *root* user) enter your own user's password, and you'll get a terminal as the root user (it will have a `#` in the prompt)
3. To add yourself to the sudoers type `sudo adduser [username] sudo` (where `[username]` is your user name)

This adds your user to the sudo users list.